# Spread operator with React Props in Typescript (error: ...could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint {})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to write a Higher Order Component in React using Typescript that receives the props, 'consumes' one of them and then passes on the remainder to the Child component.

```
function testConnect<T>(Child: React.ComponentType<T>): React.ComponentType<T> {

  type InitialState = {
    iS: StoreShape.State;
  };

  type LAP = InitialState & T;

  const Connector = (props: LAP) => {
    const { iS, ...rest } = props;
    // do something with iS
    return (
      <Child // Visual Studio complains about this line.
        {...rest}
      />
    );
  };

  return Connector;
}
```

However this fails with the error: `'Pick<LAP, Exclude<keyof T, "iS">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'`

I would like to know not only if there's anything I can do about it, but also why this happens at all.

Comment: Actually, just pass `{...props}` on.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've acutally been doing. But I'd like to know what the solution is, or whether it's just a problem with React types - other experiements don't seem to have the same problem, but it could just be a complexity issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, Typescript is catching a Problem with your component:

```
 const Component = testConnect(({ iS }) => <div>{iS}</div>);

 <Component iS={...} />
```

So you either have to

(a) pass on all props (instead of just rest) to the component.

```
   <Child   {...props} />
```

(b) Make sure that no prop named "iS" can be passed in by excluding the key `iS` from T:

```
 testConnect<T>(Child: React.ComponentType<Omit<T, "iS">>>): React.ComponentType<T> {
```

Comment: I didn't see your edit, so I've put a bounty on this. Having just re-read your answer it seems perfect, though, so thank you! It solved my problem, but I'l wait to tick it until the bounty expires just in case a representative from the React dev team turns up! ;) [edit: May I suggest you edit your answer just to include answer 'b'? While 'a' does work it feels hacky, whereas I suspect 'b' is an excellent, non-hacky canonical answer]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem, not the most elegant one, but it stops to complain:

```
type InitialState = {
    iS: StoreShape.State;
};

function testConnect<T>(Child: React.ComponentType<T>): React.ComponentType<T> {
    const Connector = (props: InitialState & Exclude<T, "iS">) => {
        const isT = (object: any): object is T => {
            return !("iS" in object);
        };

        const { iS, ...rest } = props;

        if (isT(rest)) {
            return (
                <Child // Visual Studio complains on this line.
                    {...rest}
                />
            );
        }

        return <Child {...props} />;
    };

    return Connector;
}
```

To your code stops to complain, you need to fix how you are passing the props to the `Child` component. He accepts `props` of type `T`. But `rest` in your case is not of type `T` (or at least TS compiler is not smart enough to figure it out), its type is `Pick<LAP, Exclude<keyof T, "iS">>` because of the `rest operator` you used.

My solution idea is just to let the compiler knows that `rest` is of type `T`, using a **custom type guard function**, but you could use other approaches, like a type casting:

```
<Child
  {...((rest as unknown) as T)}
/>
```

I hope it helps you!